# Как изменить стартовую страницу в админке Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Как изменить стартовую страницу в админке Spree? По умолчанию идет страница /admin/orders, необходимо /admin/products. Пробую редиректом в роутере, get '/admin/orders', to: redirect('/admin/products')
но перенаправление игнорируется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдите файл [spree/backend/config/routes.rb](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/backend/config/routes.rb) . В конце этого файла есть строка

```
get Spree.admin_path, to: redirect(Spree.admin_path + '/orders'), as: :admin
```

Вам нужно заменить ее на

```
get Spree.admin_path, to: redirect(Spree.admin_path + '/products'), as: :admin
```

Для того, чтобы переопределить роут в вашем приложении в файле config/routes.rb определите его до точки монтирования роутов энджина `Spree`

```
get Spree.admin_path, to: redirect(Spree.admin_path + '/products'), as: :admin
mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/'
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ, строки указанной вами не нашел, но есть такая   get '/admin', to: 'admin/root#index', as: :admin
заменил здесь 'admin/root#index' на 'admin/products#index' и получил желаемое, но меня смущает, что приходится править роутер гема (ruby-2.3.0/gems/spree_backend-3.0.9/config/routes.rb), хотелось бы обновляться. Не подскажите есть ли способ, который не затрагивает ядро spree?

Comment: @ТарасВеселый дополнил ответ

Comment: спасибо! Переопределить роут получилось, но в моем случае строка выглядит так:
  get '/admin', to: 'spree/admin/products#index', as: :admin

Comment: @ТарасВеселый Так, без редиректа, даже лучше.